# Check if cell of row in pandas dataframe contains NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which I want to use to create an xml file from. I need to create different child elements depending on if certain rows contain NaN or not.

I have the below if statement, but it never gets evaluated as true..

```
if(pd.notna(row.ErrorCode)):
```

An example of a row in my dataframe for which I would want this to be evaluated as True is ..

```
01N037757341    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN E2230   System exception encountered processin...   AB231   00AX    2022-04-12  TN08RRO
```

The errorCode is in the correct ErrorCode field but it doesn't recognise this as notna. I have tried notnull as well, but can't get this to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you include a bit more data to help us understand your problem?

Comment: Does using `pd.isnull` instead of `pd.notna` solve your problem? If not, please add an example DataFrame to make the problem statement clearer.

Comment: Sorry. This was my bad. The rows were being excluded by prior if statement. Thanks.